# Input, limitar el numero de caracteres después del punto al escribir

Tags: php, javascript, input

Buen dia,  tengo un input que registra el precio de algo, y quisiera limitar escribir a solo 2 caracteres después de escribir el punto.

```
        <input type="number" name="ofer" list="listapesos" class="form-control formx" placeholder="0" min="0" max="100" maxlength="3"  
        onkeypress="return ( (event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57) )">
```

Comment: Y que haz intentado para realizar exactamente eso de limitar a solo dos decimales despues de la coma?, primero coloca porfavor aquello que haz intentado del lado de javascript, ademas ten en cuenta que si quieres que el usuario introduzca especificamente numeros existe un input tipo number que es muchisimo mejor para lo que requieres.

Comment: Intenta con el atributo [step="0.01"](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/input/number#step) para limitar a dos decimales.